# Query cakephp don't work

Tags: cakephp

I have this query in controller. It is a simple insert data in the database.

```
$this->User->query('INSERT INTO users(CF,phone,username,email,city,firstname,lastname,active,group_id) VALUES ('$CF','$phone','$username','$email','$city','$name','$name','$active','$group_id')');
```

And this is the model:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * User Model
 *
 * @property Group $Group
 * @property User $ParentUser
 * @property User $ChildUser
 * @property Facility $Facility
 * @property ServiceCategory $ServiceCategory
 */
class User extends AppModel {

/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'name';


    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */


 public $virtualFields = array(
    // 'name' => 'CONCAT(User.lastname, " ", User.firstname)'
    'name' => 'CONCAT(lastname, " ", firstname)'
);


    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Group' => array(
            'className' => 'Group',
            'foreignKey' => 'group_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        ), 'Gender'
    );

    public $hasMany = array('Bid');

/**
 * hasAndBelongsToMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Facility' => array(
            'className' => 'Facility',
            'joinTable' => 'facilities_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'facility_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
        ),
        'ServiceCategory' => array(
            'className' => 'ServiceCategory',
            'joinTable' => 'service_categories_users',
            'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'service_category_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
        )
    );

}
```

But the answer is a blank page. The cakephp version is 2. Can anyone help? If you can explain to me where I'm wrong so I will not repeat the same mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely issue that your debug level is 0 (meaning it won't show you what the actual error is). Try changing debug to 2 in your `config/core.php` then run the file again.

If that's not it, a blank page can sometimes occur if you have some whitespace after a close `?>` tag in a `.php` file (Controller/Model/Component/..etc.) Look at the end of your files, and get rid of any unnecessary closing `?>` tags (you don't need to close php tags in a php file).

Answer (score 1):

Why would you do inserts like that when using a framework with a magnificent ORM. Your solution opens up your application to SQL-injections.

Do it the right way.

```
$data = array(
    'CF' => $CF,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'username' => $username,
    'email' => $email,
    'city' => $city,
    'name' => $name,
    'active' => $active,
    'group_id' => $group_id
);

$this->User->create();
$this->User->save($data);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html